# vba - how to code based on number of times defined variable is found

Tags: excel, vba

The scenario is I have a claim with multiple lines. I need to add some code based on whether or not "0762" is found once vs more than once.

In Scenario1, I would need to split lines 1 & 2 off
In Scenario2, I wouldn't need to split anything, just deny line 1.

I just don't know the initial code of how to write "if this is found only once in the whole X amount of lines, then do Y, else if found more than once, do Z"

The code will essentially scan all the lines and need to know if the variable was only found once or more than once.

Scenario1:

Ln1 - 0762

Ln2 - 0762

Ln3 - 0450

Scenario2:

Ln1 - 0762

Ln2 - 0450

Can anyone help? I hope my explanation was sufficient - so sorry in advance if I couldn't explain better.

Edit:

Below is my current code, which

1. finds all RC762 on a claim, and splits them off onto a seperate claim, and overrides and processes both the original and split
2. if the claim is already a split claim, check lines for RC762. If they are all RC762, override and release.

What I need to add is if RC762 has modifier GZ, deny RC762 with AC "458" and process. *AND* if it is the ONLY RC762 on the claim - do not split it off, but if there are multiple RC762, split them all off and deny only the line with modifier GZ.

I am struggling to code it on how to determine whether or not there is only 1x RC762 or multiple, after it scans all the lines, as that will determine the coding for what to do next.

```
    AppActivate UseIBM1
    HE.Connect "A" 'BlueZone
    PAUSE 1

'   If M00003 or M00033 contract but not PVD# 022921, enter SPI overrides and release - 2019_1210. MF
        Select Case QmyClaim(1).aaLine_K_Detail(1).KPriCont
            Case Is = "M00003", "M00033"
                If Left(QmyClaim(1).PvdNum, 6) <> "022921" Then
                    Utilities.GoToPclmScrnNumber "6", UseIBM1, "10", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
                    Utilities.PassNoteToPCLM_RemarksGHC "MPT025", UseIBM1, "11", "BUTTONS"
                    Utilities.AssignSPIcodeUB "8H9", UseIBM1, "12", "BUTTONS"
                    Utilities.AssignSPIcodeUB "REO", UseIBM1, "13", "BUTTONS"
                    Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "14", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
                    ActionEntry = "SPI Overrides Entered - Medicare contract without PVD#022921."
                    GoTo EditCheck
                End If
            Case Else
            'do nothing
        End Select

'       If M10 contract, enter SPI overrides and release
        If QmyClaim(1).aaLine_K_Detail(1).KPriCont = "M00010" Then
            AppActivate UseIBM1
            HE.Connect "A" 'BlueZone
            PAUSE 1

            Utilities.GoToPclmScrnNumber "6", UseIBM1, "15", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
            Utilities.PassNoteToPCLM_RemarksGHC "MPT025", UseIBM1, "16", "BUTTONS"
            Utilities.AssignSPIcodeUB "8H9", UseIBM1, "17", "BUTTONS"
            Utilities.AssignSPIcodeUB "REO", UseIBM1, "18", "BUTTONS"
            Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "19", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
            ActionEntry = "Released - M00010 contract."
            GoTo EditCheck
        End If

        AppActivate UseIBM1
        HE.Connect "A" 'BlueZone
        PAUSE 1

'       If claim is already split, check if all lines are RC762 '2019_1210. MF
        SC = Trim(HE.CurrentHost.TextRC(4, 16, 1))

        If SC = "0" Then
            'do nothing, continue
        Else
            For SCL = 1 To QmyClaim(1).aaLastLineArrayPosition
                If QmyClaim(1).aaLine_UB(SCL).Rev = "0762" Then
                'do nothing
                Else
'                   Skip claim for manual review if any other RC on split claim '2019_1210. MF
                    ActionEntry = "Skipped - Claim already split. Manual review needed."
                    'clear screen
                    Utilities.PressKey "pageup", True, UseIBM1, "20", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
                    GoTo ENDOFCLAIM
                End If
            Next SCL

'           All lines are RC762 then enter SPI overrides and add macro stamp '2019_1210. MF
            If QmyClaim(1).aaLine_UB(SCL).Rev = "" Then
                Utilities.PassNoteToPCLM_RemarksGHC "MPT025", UseIBM1, "21", "BUTTONS"
                Utilities.AssignSPIcodeUB "8H9", UseIBM1, "22", "BUTTONS"
                Utilities.AssignSPIcodeUB "REO", UseIBM1, "23", "BUTTONS"
                Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "24", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
                ActionEntry = "All lines RC762 - SPI overrides entered"
                GoTo EditCheck
            End If
        End If

'       Notate split on original claim
        Utilities.GoToPclmScrnNumber "6", UseIBM1, "25", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
        HE.CurrentHost.PutText "1/2", 13, 39 'COMMENTS FIELD
        Utilities.PassNoteToPCLM_RemarksGHC "MPT025", UseIBM1, "26", "BUTTONS"
        HE.CurrentHost.PutText "Y", 5, 66 'SPLIT CLAIM SC=Y
        Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "27", , "NO", "BUTTONS"

'       Find lines with RC762 and split from claim
        Z = 11

        SplitLine = Trim(HE.CurrentHost.TextRC(Z, 2, 1))

        For Y = 1 To QmyClaim(1).aaLastLineArrayPosition
            LineItem = Trim(HE.CurrentHost.TextRC(Z, 4, 3))

                If LineItem = "" Then
                    EOD = Trim(HE.CurrentHost.TextRC(22, 2, 3))

                    If EOD = "967" Then
                        GoTo SkipF8
                    End If

                    Utilities.PressKey "F8", False, UseIBM1, "28", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
                    Z = 11
                ElseIf LineItem = "099" Then
                    'clear screen
                    Utilities.PressKey "pageup", True, UseIBM1, "29", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
                    ActionEntry = "Skipped - More than 99 lines.  Manually split. "
                    GoTo ENDOFCLAIM
                End If

                If QmyClaim(1).aaLine_UB(Y).Rev = "0762" Then
                    HE.CurrentHost.PutText "S", Z, 2
                End If

        Z = Z + 1
        Next Y

SkipF8:
'       Process split claim and notate split 2/2
        HE.CurrentHost.PutText "Y", 7, 2
        Utilities.PressKey "F3", False, UseIBM1, "30", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
        Utilities.PressKey "F9", False, UseIBM1, "31", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
        Select Case myOutcome(1).Edit1_8(1).ErrNum
            Case Is = "550", "552"
                'do nothing
            Case Else
                Utilities.ProcessPCLMClmPendPerPTAI UseIBM1, "32", "BUTTONS"
                GoTo Pend
        End Select
        Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "33", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
Pend:
        Utilities.GoToPclmScrnNumber "6", UseIBM1, "34", , "NO", "BUTTONS"
        Utilities.PassNoteToPCLM_RemarksGHC "MPT025", UseIBM1, "35", "BUTTONS"
        HE.CurrentHost.PutText "2/2", 13, 39 'COMMENTS FIELD

EnterSPI:
'       Assign SPI override
        Utilities.AssignSPIcodeUB "8H9", UseIBM1, "36", "BUTTONS"
        Utilities.AssignSPIcodeUB "REO", UseIBM1, "37", "BUTTONS"
        ActionEntry = ActionEntry & "RC762 split from claim"
        Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "38", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Need the code to understand what you're doing as BB said, can you show us what you've got?

Comment: Hi BigBen and Peyter, I have edited my original post. Sorry about that - I didn't add the code originally because I didn't have an idea for the code on the part I am inquerying about.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting for anyone that happens to be looking for the answer for future reference, it was a Boolean statement trigger that was the answer to the problem.

Essentially: Dim the Boolean, set it False, and then inside a For/Next, once the variable is found in your If statement the first time, trigger it to be true. Then, once the variable is found again, if the Boolean is true, exit the For. So if the variable is only found once, it will complete the action, else it will exit the for if found more than once and do nothing/continue.

based on the code i wrote above, this was what I added at the top:

```
'   If RC762 with modifier GZ is only RC762 on claim, deny line
    For Y = 1 To QmyClaim(1).aaLastLineArrayPosition
        If QmyClaim(1).aaLine_UB(Y).Rev = "0762" Then
            If RC762GZ = True Then
                Exit For
            End If

            If QmyClaim(1).aaLine_UB(Y).Mod1 = "GZ" Then
                RC762GZ = True
                RC762GzLn = Y
            ElseIf QmyClaim(1).aaLine_UB(Y).Mod2 = "GZ" Then
                RC762GZ = True
                RC762GzLn = Y
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

        If Y = QmyClaim(1).aaLastLineArrayPosition Then
            Utilities.DenyLineWithActionCode RC762GzLn, "458", UseIBM1, "1", "BUTTONS"
            Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "19", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
            ActionEntry = "RC762 with modifier GZ denied AC 458."
            GoTo EditCheck
        End If
    Next Y
```